# how to make mongodb 'upsert' to insert new documents as well as update existing ones

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mean-stack

in my MEAN app, I have a situation, where I'm reading in some csv data line by line, and using 'upsert' to update the existing records, as well as to insert those, which do not match the 'CSCOpportunityID' field value:

```
if(metaFields.subjectCategory === 'SalesforceData'){
                            //Here we will use the upsert logic to either insert new, or update existing records

                            for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                                //console.log(result[i]);

                                var inserted = 0;

                                for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                                    var dataRecord = result[i];

                                    dataRecord.OriginalDocumentName = fileName;
                                    dataRecord.DocumentAuthor = metaFields.documentAuthor;
                                    dataRecord.TabName = tabName;
                                    dataRecord.SubjectCategory = metaFields.subjectCategory;
                                    dataRecord.Subject = metaFields.subject;
                                    dataRecord.DateDocumentProduced = metaFields.dateDocumentProduced;
                                    dataRecord.DateDocumentReceived = metaFields.dateDocumentReceived;
                                    dataRecord.DocumentSubmitter = metaFields.documentSubmitter;
                                    dataRecord.DocumentReviewer = metaFields.documentReviewer;
                                    dataRecord.OriginalSource = metadataFields.originalSource,
                                        dataRecord.DataVersion = metadataFields.dataVersion,
                                        dataRecord.DataFields = newCsvLines[0];

                                    collection.update(
                                    {
                                        CSCOpportunityId: dataRecord.CSCOpportunityID
                                    },
                                        {
                                            $set: {

                                                OriginalDocumentName:   dataRecord.OriginalDocumentName,
                                                DocumentAuthor: dataRecord.DocumentAuthor,
                                                TabName:    dataRecord.TabName,
                                                SubjectCategory:    dataRecord.SubjectCategory,
                                                Subject:    dataRecord.Subject,
                                                DateDocumentProduced:   dataRecord.DateDocumentProduced,
                                                DateDocumentReceived:   dataRecord.DateDocumentReceived,
                                                DocumentSubmitter:  dataRecord.DocumentSubmitter,
                                                DocumentReviewer:   dataRecord.DocumentReviewer,
                                                OriginalSource: dataRecord.OriginalSource,
                                                DataVersion:    dataRecord.DataVersion,
                                                DataFields: dataRecord.DataFields,

                                                CSCOpportunityID : dataRecord.CSCOpportunityID,
                                                OpportunityName: dataRecord.OpportunityName ,
                                                AccountName : dataRecord.AccountName,
                                                OpportunityOwner : dataRecord.OpportunityOwner,
                                                Stage : dataRecord.Stage,
                                                Industry : dataRecord.Industry,
                                                ACV : dataRecord.ACV,
                                                RevenueStartDate : dataRecord.RevenueStartDate,
                                                RevenueTerm : dataRecord.RevenueTerm,
                                                ProbabilityPct : dataRecord.ProbabilityPct,
                                                DealRegion : dataRecord.DealRegion
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {upsert: true},
                                        {multi:true}

                                        //if (++inserted == result.length) {
                                        //    console.log("finished");
                                        //    //db.close();
                                        //}
                                    );
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

The update parts works, but the insert part does not, because I do not know how to make an insert, when the value of 'CSCOpportunityID' finds no match.

What is the proper way of handlding this?

Comment: I wonder how even update works, since you misplaced `{multi:true}` in callback parameter and update will only return a promise.

Comment: Right you are. You can post it as an answer, and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `update` method takes 4th argument as callback function. Since you provided an object `{multi: true}`, it won't make any db call, only return a promise. Correct syntax is:

```
 collection.update(query, fieldsToSet, {upsert: true, multi: true}, function(err,doc){

 })
```